# Adding the next character on a string C++

Tags: c++

I did get the next character on a string `(hello-->ifmmp)` but in the case of hello* i want to be able to still display the * as the exception, it can be also a number but i guess it does not matter because is not in the alphabet.

this is my code, Where should be the else if? 
There is another option but i dont find it optimized, it is to add inside the first for loop this:

```
string other="123456789!@#$%^&*()";

 for(int z=0;z<other.length();z++)
   {
       if(str[i]==other[z])
       str2+=other[z];
   }
```

Then this is the main code;

```
int main()
{

string str = "hello*";
string str2="";
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<alphabet.length();j++)
   {
       if(str[i]==alphabet[j])
       {
       str2+=alphabet[j+1];
       }

   }

  }

    cout<<str2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't find your wording very clear - could you provide a few example cases of input strings, the output you want, and the output you currently get?

Comment: What is the actual output of your program? What is the expected output? What is the purpose of your program? What problem is it supposed to solve? What is the assignment or exercise you're supposed to answer? Have you tried to step through the code in a debugger to see what it does? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hello, I am sorry if my English is not very good, My input is hello, and the output ifmmp , what I am trying to achieve is to get the same thing, but if i have some kind of special character included in the word ignore it and add it to the output. I don't know if I am explaining.

Comment: What should be the output for `zzzz`?

Comment: Should be aaaa, but in this case that option could not be executed

Comment: How about a simple `else` clause for unrecognized characters?

Comment: And read a little bit more about the modulo operator `%` for the wrap-around. Then you don't need the inner loop at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `isalpha` in the standard library which is very useful for classification.

You could do something like this.

(This kind of exercise usually assumes the ASCII encoding of the English alphabet, and this is a very ASCII-specific solution. If you want a different alphabet or a different character encoding, you need to handle that yourself.)

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello*Zzz?";
    std::string str2;
    for (char c: str)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(c))
        {
            c += 1;
            if (!std::isalpha(c)) 
            {
                 // Went too far; wrap around to 'a' or 'A'.
                 c -= 26;
            }
        }
        str2 += c;
    }
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Ifmmp*Aaa?
```

Comment: You might want to add a note that this is very ASCII specific, and that the C++ specification is open for other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

I like functions. They solve a lot of problems. For example, if you take the code you already have, paste it into a function, and give it a little tweak

```
char findreplacement(char ch, const std::string & alphabet)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++)
    {
        if (ch == alphabet[j])
        {
            return alphabet[(j+1) % alphabet.length()]; 
            // return the replacement character
            // using modulo, %, to handle wrap around z->a
        }
    }
    return ch; // found no replacement. Return original character.
}
```

you can call the function

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    str2 += findreplacement(str[i], alphabet);
}
```

to build `str2`. Consider using a range-based `for` here:

```
for (char ch: str)
{
    str2 += findreplacement(ch, alphabet);
}
```

It's cleaner and a lot harder to screw up.